Добавление себя в автозагрузку
При PyInstaller или любого компилятора .exe необходимо сделать добавление в автозагрузку

import os
import sys
import getpass
import shutil

filename = 'hello.exe'

if os.getcwd() != f'C:\\Windows\\system32':
    shutil.copy2(sys.argv[0],f'C:\\Users\\{getpass.getuser()}\\Appdata\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\{filename}')

    # код если не в автозагрузке
else:
    # код если в автозагрузке

